# Searching using multiple fields from one column in php

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to search data using multiple fields from one column? For example column name is 'Job Title', and in the first field I key in 'HR' and second field I key in 'Human Resources'. After I click on search button it will search 'HR' and 'Human Resources' from column 'Job Title'. Below is my code,

```
        <form action="process/searchprocess.php" method="GET">
        <tr>
           <th>
                <br><br>Job Title<br><input type="text" name="Designation"  />
            </th>
            <th>
                <br><br>Business Nature / Company Name<br><input type="text" name="BusinessNature"  />
            </th>
        <th valign="center">
                <br><br>Email<select name="Email" >

                    <option value="" >All</option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="Nil">No</option>
                </select>

            </th>
        </tr>
```

And this is my php code,

```
                            <?php
                            session_start();

                            // Create connection
                            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password , $db);

                            // Check connection
                            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                            }




                            set_time_limit(0);
                            $query1 = $_GET['Designation'];
                            $query2 = $_GET['BusinessNature'];
                            $query3 = $_GET['State'];
                            $query4 = $_GET['Designation2'];
                            $query5 = $_GET['Designation3'];
                            $query6 = $_GET['Designation4'];
                            $query7 = $_GET['Designation5'];
                            $query8 = $_GET['Designation6'];
                            $query9 = $_GET['Designation7'];
                            $query10 = $_GET['Designation8'];
                            $query11 = $_GET['Designation9'];
                            $query12 = $_GET['Designation10'];
                            $query13 = $_GET['BusinessNature2'];
                            $query14 = $_GET['BusinessNature3'];
                            $query15 = $_GET['BusinessNature4'];
                            $query16 = $_GET['BusinessNature5'];
                            $query17 = $_GET['BusinessNature6'];
                            $query18 = $_GET['BusinessNature7'];
                            $query19 = $_GET['BusinessNature8'];
                            $query20 = $_GET['BusinessNature9'];
                            $query21 = $_GET['BusinessNature10'];
                            $Email = $_GET['Email'];

                            ?>

                            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                            <head>                                                        

                            </head>
                            <body>
                            <div id=headerbg>
                            <div id=headerwrap>
                                <div id=header>
                                    <div style="margin-right: 100px;">
                                    <BRANDING:DefaultProductLogo>
                                        <div id=logo> <a href="../adminpage.php"> <img style="border: none;" src="http://www.xendmailer.com/emv2/system/data/templates/enhanced_english/media/images/logo.png" width="203" height="21" /></a></div><!--End for id=logo-->
                                    </BRANDING:DefaultProductLogo>



                                    </div>    
                                </div><!--End for id=header-->
                            </div><!--End for id=headerwrap-->
                            </div><!--End for id=bg-->
                            <div id=spacer></div><!--End for id=spacer-->

                            <div id=contentwrap>
                                <form action="export.php" method="GET">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            <!-- <br><input type="submit" value="Export" align="center" /> -->
                                            <button class="button button">Export</button>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="query1" value="<?php echo $query1; ?>">
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="query2" value="<?php echo $query2; ?>">
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="query3" value="<?php echo $query3; ?>">
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <input type="hidden" name="Email" value="<?php echo $Email; ?>">
                                        </th>

                                    </tr>
                                </form>

                            <?php
                                // $query = $_GET['client_name'];   

                                if ( $query1 == null && $query2 == null && $query3 == null && $query4 == null && $query5 == null)
                                {
                                    // echo "Please at least insert one the value";
                                    echo "<script language = 'Javascript'>";
                                    echo "alert('Please insert at least  one value to search!');";
                                    echo "location.href = '../adminpage.php';</script>";
                                }

                                else
                                {     
                                    $query1 = htmlspecialchars($query1); 
                                    $query2 = htmlspecialchars($query2); 
                                    $query3 = htmlspecialchars($query3); 
                                    $query4 = htmlspecialchars($query4);
                                    $query5 = htmlspecialchars($query5);
                                    $query6 = htmlspecialchars($query6);
                                    $query7 = htmlspecialchars($query7); 
                                    $query8 = htmlspecialchars($query8); 
                                    $query9 = htmlspecialchars($query9); 
                                    $query10 = htmlspecialchars($query10);
                                    $query11 = htmlspecialchars($query11);
                                    $query12 = htmlspecialchars($query12);
                                    $query13 = htmlspecialchars($query13); 
                                    $query14 = htmlspecialchars($query14); 
                                    $query15 = htmlspecialchars($query15); 
                                    $query16 = htmlspecialchars($query16);
                                    $query17 = htmlspecialchars($query17);
                                    $query18 = htmlspecialchars($query18);  
                                    $query19 = htmlspecialchars($query19);  
                                    $query20 = htmlspecialchars($query20);  
                                    $query21 = htmlspecialchars($query21);
                                    $Email = htmlspecialchars($Email);  
                                    // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

                                    $query1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query1);
                                    $query2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query2);
                                    $query3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query3);
                                    $query4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query4);
                                    $query5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query5);
                                    $query6 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query6);
                                    $query7 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query7);
                                    $query8 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query8);
                                    $query9 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query9);
                                    $query10 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query10);
                                    $query11 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query11);
                                    $query12 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query12);
                                    $query13 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query13);
                                    $query14 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query14);
                                    $query15 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query15);
                                    $query16 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query16);
                                    $query17 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query17);
                                    $query18 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query18);
                                    $query19 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query19);
                                    $query20 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query20);
                                    $query21 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query21);
                                    $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Email);
                                    // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection




                                            <?php




                                            // $query = "SELECT * FROM user_info " . $where . " order by ID";
                                            // $raw_results = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die (mysqli_error());


                                    if ($query1 == 0)
                                    {

                                            $where = "";
                                            $whereConditions = array();
                                            if(strlen($query1) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions[] = "Designation LIKE '%" . $query1 . "%'";
                                            }
                                            if(strlen($query4) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions[] = "Designation LIKE '%" . $query4 . "%'";
                                            }
                                            if(strlen($query5) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions[] = "Designation LIKE '%" . $query5 . "%'";
                                            }
                                             if(strlen($query6) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions[] = "Designation LIKE '%" . $query6 . "%'";
                                            }
                                             if(strlen($query7) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions[] = "Designation LIKE '%" . $query7 . "%'";
                                            }
                                             if(strlen($query8) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions[] = "Designation LIKE '%" . $query8 . "%'";
                                            }
                                             if(strlen($query9) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions[] = "Designation LIKE '%" . $query9 . "%'";
                                            }
                                             if(strlen($query10) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions[] = "Designation LIKE '%" . $query10 . "%'";
                                            }
                                             if(strlen($query11) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions[] = "Designation LIKE '%" . $query11 . "%'";
                                            }
                                             if(strlen($query12) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions[] = "Designation LIKE '%" . $query12 . "%'";
                                            }
                                            if(count($whereConditions) > 0) {
                                              $where = " (" . implode(" OR ", $whereConditions) . ")";
                                            }

                                            $where2 = "";
                                            $whereConditions2 = array();
                                            if(strlen($query2) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions2[] = "BusinessNature LIKE '%" . $query2 . "%' or Company LIKE '%" . $query2 . "%'";
                                            }
                                            if(strlen($query13) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions2[] = "BusinessNature LIKE '%" . $query13 . "%' or Company LIKE '%" . $query13 . "%'";
                                            }
                                            if(strlen($query14) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions2[] = "BusinessNature LIKE '%" . $query14 . "%' or Company LIKE '%" . $query14 . "%'";
                                            }
                                            if(strlen($query15) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions2[] = "BusinessNature LIKE '%" . $query15 . "%' or Company LIKE '%" . $query15 . "%'";
                                            }
                                            if(strlen($query16) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions2[] = "BusinessNature LIKE '%" . $query16 . "%' or Company LIKE '%" . $query16 . "%'";
                                            }
                                            if(strlen($query17) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions2[] = "BusinessNature LIKE '%" . $query17 . "%' or Company LIKE '%" . $query17 . "%'";
                                            }
                                            if(strlen($query18) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions2[] = "BusinessNature LIKE '%" . $query18 . "%' or Company LIKE '%" . $query18 . "%'";
                                            }
                                            if(strlen($query19) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions2[] = "BusinessNature LIKE '%" . $query19 . "%' or Company LIKE '%" . $query19 . "%'";
                                            }
                                            if(strlen($query20) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions2[] = "BusinessNature LIKE '%" . $query20 . "%' or Company LIKE '%" . $query20 . "%'";
                                            }
                                            if(strlen($query21) > 0) {
                                              $whereConditions2[] = "BusinessNature LIKE '%" . $query21 . "%' or Company LIKE '%" . $query21 . "%'";
                                            }
                                            if(count($whereConditions2) > 0) {
                                              $where2 = " (" . implode(" OR ", $whereConditions2) . ")";
                                            }

                                            $raw_results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE " . $where . " and " . $where2 . "  and (State LIKE '%".$query3."%') and (Email LIKE '%".$Email."%') order by ID") or die (mysqli_error());

                                            if(mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > null){ // if one or more rows are returned do following
                                                ?>
                                                <table  width="100%" >
                                                        <tr align="center">
                                                            <th>ID</th>
                                                            <th>Tag</th>
                                                            <th>Company</th>
                                                            <th>Designation</th>
                                                            <th>Email</th>
                                                            <th>State</th>
                                                            <th>Business Nature</th>
                                                            <th>Data code</th>
                                                        </tr>

                                                <?php 
                                                while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results)){
                                                    ?>

                                                        <tr align="center" style="margin-left: 100px;">
                                                            <td valign="top"><?php echo $results["ID"]; ?></td>
                                                            <td  valign="middle"><?php echo $results["Tag"]; ?></td>
                                                            <td valign="middle"><?php echo $results["Company"]; ?></td>
                                                            <td valign="middle"><?php echo $results["Designation"]; ?></td>
                                                            <td valign="middle"><?php echo $results["Email"]; ?></td>
                                                            <td valign="middle"><?php echo $results["State"]; ?></td>
                                                            <td valign="middle"><?php echo $results["BusinessNature"]; ?></td>
                                                            <td valign="middle"><?php echo $results["Datacode"]; ?></td>
                                                        </tr>


                                                <?php
                                                }
                                                 ?></table><?php
                                            }



                                            else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
                                                // echo "No results";
                                                echo "<script language = 'Javascript'>";
                                                echo "alert('No Result!');";
                                                echo "location.href = '../adminpage.php';</script>";
                                            }




                                    }
                                }
                            ?>

                            </div><!--End for id=contentwrap-->



                            </body>
                            </html>
```

I have 1 job title text field, and 1 Company text field. When I only key in to Company text field, it shows this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'and (BusinessNature LIKE '%chemical%' or Company LIKE
>   '%chemical%')

It means Job title field is required. Can I know what is this error?

Check here,

Insert one field only http://spaceforemail.com/1.PNG

Result http://spaceforemail.com/2.PNG

Insert two fields http://spaceforemail.com/3.PNG

Result http://spaceforemail.com/4.PNG

Comment: Yes, this is possible. But I don't think that's the answer you wanted. Please read [ask].

Comment: What does "It only search for &query two" mean?

Comment: @NicoHaase it means that the result only shows for the second field.

Comment: Why do they have the same name?

Comment: @NicoHaase because I want to search from the same column in database.

Comment: You can name the input fields independetly form the database. Try what I've suggested in the answer

Answer (score 0):

A first approach: the two input fields should have distinguishable names, otherwise PHP won't be able to use the first value.

Additionally, you should only use the input fields that contain something, like the following:

```
$where = "";
$whereConditions = array();
if(strlen($query1) > 0) {
  $whereConditions[] = "Designation LIKE '%" . $query1 . "%'";
}
if(strlen($query2) > 0) {
  $whereConditions[] = "Designation LIKE '%" . $query2 . "%'";
}
if(count($whereConditions) > 0) {
  $where = "WHERE (" . implode(" OR ", $whereConditions) . ")";
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_info " . $where . " order by ID";
$raw_results = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
```

Comment: Hi,I have edit the question. I put different name between those two field. Now the problem is when I insert only in one field the result shows all. and when I insert both of the field only it shows the correct result.

Comment: Yeah, because your query contains `Designation LIKE '%%'` which holds true for **all** rows. See my edited answer

Comment: Hi, now the problem is I need to key in all field to find the result. It shows   all designation when I only key in one field.

Comment: Can you edit your code accordingly? If you use my posted code, does it really still fail?

Comment: I have 3 job title text field, and 1 Company text field. When I only key in to Company text field, it shows this error 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'and (BusinessNature LIKE '%chemical%' or Company LIKE '%chemical%')
 It means Job title field is required.

Comment: And what is that exact query that is used? Your given code did not show any connection to a field named `BusinessNature` or `Company`. Could you open a new question for this?

Comment: Hi @Nico Haase, I have updated the question. Do you mind to check it, cause I have try it multiples time and still got the same error

Comment: What is "the same error"? Can you add the full generated query and the exact error message to the question?

Comment: Hi, you can check from the image link.

Comment: No, thank you. Please never add such relevant information in images, they should be added through code.

Comment: Hi @Nico Haase I have uploaded those image to my server and provided the links.

Comment: Thats fine, but if you are searching for help, add error messages in text form.

Comment: Even if I feel like a parrot repeating stuff over and over: Can you add the **full generated query** to the question?

Comment: Hi @Nico Haase , I have added my full code into the question.